# Passport Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a passport validation that depends on its format, I created 2 input bar. The first input bar that only allows user to input 2 letters only and the second input bar only allows to input 7 number. What javascript function to validate user input 2 letters only not numbers and to input 7 numbers only not letters on its respected input bars

Here is what I have so far

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="passportno" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Passport No.</p></label>
          
<input size="1" name="passportno" class="form-control" placeholder=""required/> -
<input  size="14" name="passportno" class="form-control" placeholder=""required/>
          
</div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @arthur also validates inputting the number/letter only

Answer (score 2):

Below code shows alert whether the input is valid input or not. If not then alert shows false. Replace alert with your code for showing message or something else.

Use `maxlength` attribute of html for maximum input characters

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        alert(/^\d+$/.test($('#passportNumber').val()));       // 2 digit number validation
        alert(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($('#passportSeries').val()));  // 7 character validation
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="passportno" class="control-label col-xs-4">
                <p class="left">Passport No.</p>
            </label>
            <input maxlength="2" id="passportNumber" class="form-control" placeholder=""required/> -
            <input maxlength="7" id="passportSeries" class="form-control" placeholder=""required/>
            <input type="button" value="submit" id="submitButton" />   
        </div>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is one of the may ways.

- Set maxlength to your input
- Have unique names to your inputs (not the same)
- Since I don't see a button to validate, I've used keyup, input (deals with copy+paste etc.)

```js
$("input").on("keyup input", function() {
 
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $.trim( $this.val() ) || "";

    if (this["name"] === "passportno") {
     val = val.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    } else {
        val = val.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
    }
 $this.val( val );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="passportno" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">Passport No.</p></label>

    <input size="1" name="passportno" class="form-control" placeholder="" required="" maxlength="2" /> -
    <input  size="14" name="passportletters" class="form-control" placeholder="" required="" maxlength="7" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested but I think Sarjan Desai's answer accepts 1 to 2 letters and 1 to 7 numbers. You can specify to match a length in both regexp:

`/^\d+$/` would be `/^\d{2}$/` and `/^\[a-zA-Z]+$/` would be `/^\[a-zA-Z]{7}$/`

Modified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        alert(/^\d{2}$/.test($('#passportNumber').val()));
        alert(/^[a-zA-Z]{7}$/.test($('#passportSeries').val()));
    });
});
```